# not able to access aws resource using aws-sdk but able to do using aws cli and web console

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am not able to access aws resource using aws-sdk. But I am able to access resources using aws cli and web console. Is there any setting I am missing I am running the nodejs code from VSCode. I have set the profile in VS code.

The below command works

```
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket node-sdk-sample-mytest123 --region us-east-1 --profile dev
```

below nodejs code is not working I get

> AccessDenied: Access Denied

[image]

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');

// Create an S3 client
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
// Create a bucket and upload something into it
var bucketName = 'node-sdk-sample-' + uuid.v4();
var keyName = 'hello_world.txt';

s3.createBucket({Bucket: bucketName}, function(err,data) {
  if (err){
    console.log(err)}
  else{
    var params = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: keyName, Body: 'Hello World!'};
    s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err)
      console.log(err)
    else
      console.log("Successfully uploaded data to " + bucketName + "/" + keyName);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running locally and you've used a custom name for your AWS credential make sure, you've updated the environment variables in the current Terminal before running the program

You can use named export in command line,

```
export AWS_PROFILE=dev
```

Comment: I running it from my desktop not as a lambda service. the above script you see i run it as "node s3-test.js" from the VSCode Terminal

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html#getting-started-nodejs-credentials